# ng-init take value from another file

Tags: arrays, angularjs, ng-init

I'm using angularJs and I must fill the array in ng-init with multiple values:

```
<div ng-init="script = [
            {tag:'tag1', title:'Title1 here', plot:'here goes the plot1'},
            {tag:'tag2', title:'Title2 here', plot:'here goes the plot2'},
            {tag:'tag3', title:'Title3 here', plot:'here goes the plot3'}
            ]">
</div>
```

as you may imagine, the "plot" field is a string which may be quite big and confusing if I write it there. Is it possible to take it from another file?
For example I may make three files called plot1, plot2, plot3 and I may call them into my HTML file

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using `ng-init`.  I'd suggest using a view controller and load the script via the following logic.

```
.controller( 'viewController', function($scope, $http){
     $http.get(<location of file to load>)
     .then( function(rsp){
          $scope.script = rsp
     })
})
```

If you wanted to load multiple files, then either make multiple requests, **or** if they are contingent upon one another, use `$q.all` to make sure you load them all:

```
$q.all([
    $http.get(<location of file1 to load>),
    $http.get(<location of file2 to load>),
    $http.get(<location of file3 to load>)
])
.then( function( rsps ){
     $scope.script = rsps
})
```

links:

- [Angularjs access local json files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649460/angularjs-access-local-json-files)
- [$q.all docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller( 'viewController', function($scope, $http){
     $http.get(url)
     .then( function(response){
          $scope.initVal = response;
     })
})

<div ng-init="initVal ">
</div>
```

Comment: why the `ng-init="initVal"`?

Comment: Can you improve the answer with some details about why it solves this best?