# Angular ng-route: show a page into a page when I redirect to a #/page "[$compile:tpload] Failed to load template:"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, route-provider, angularjs-ng-route

I'm using ng-route to show a page called "london.htm" (in the same directory of my principal page) into this principal page, such this example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#london">City 1</a>
<a href="#paris">City 2</a>

<p>Click on the links to read about London and Paris.</p>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/london", {
        templateUrl : "london.htm"
    })
    .when("/paris", {
        templateUrl : "paris.htm"
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

This is my principal page, when I call `<div ng-view></div>` to show "london.htm" page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0069)https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/ -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/puzzle.png" />
      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/angular-bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/mainBoot.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/scrollbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/noscroll_numberfield.css">
    
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script> 
 <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.js"></script> -->

      
      
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/deployeePanel.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts/rest-services.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <!--  <script src="scripts/emailchecker.js"></script>  --> 
    <script src="scripts/angular-bootstrap-datepicker.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <!-- <script src="scripts/number-directive.js"></script> -->
    <script type="application/javascript"></script>
    
    <title>Pannello dipendenti</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="./styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="./styles/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <style id="holderjs-style" type="text/css"></style></head>

  <body ng-app="StaffManagement" ng-controller="StaffController" background="images/sfondoblu3.png">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand">FDDispenser</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/#">Pannello Dipendenti</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/#">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="edit_employee.html">Aggiungi/Modifica Dipendente</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/#">Reports</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/#">Analytics</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/#">Export</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Nav item</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Nav item again</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">One more nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Another nav item</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">More navigation</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Nav item again</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">One more nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Another nav item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
            
          <div ng-view></div>
            
            
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <!--  <script src="./Dashboard Template for Bootstrap_files/jquery.min.js.download"></script> -->
    <script src="./scripts/bootstrap.min.js.download"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/docs.min.js.download"></script>
        

</body></html>
```

This is my js page when I make call ng-route:

```js
    var app = angular.module("StaffManagement", ['ng-bootstrap-datepicker','ngRoute']);  
           
            //Controller Part  
            app.controller("StaffController", function($scope, $filter, $http, restService) {  
                
                 
                $scope.staffs = [];  
                $scope.staffLast = [];  
                $scope.staffForm = {  
                      idstaff : -1,    
                        staffType: {
                        idstaffType: 2,
                        type: "Dipendente"
                      },
                      name: "",
                      surname: "",
                      birthDate: "",
                      phone: "",
                      gender: true,
                      working: true,
                      staffLogin: {
                        idstaffLogin: -1,
                        email: "",
                       // pass: "",
                         
                      }
                };  
                
                $scope.staffLoginForm = {  
                      idstaffLogin: -1,
                      email: "",
                    //  pass: ""
                };  
                
                $scope.selectg = [
                     {name:'uomo', type: true},
                     {name:'donna', type: false}
                ];
                
                $scope.dateold = {
                    getdateold: ""
                    };
                
                 $scope.datepickerOptions = {
                    format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
                    language: 'it',
                    startDate: "01/01/1900",
                    endDate: new Date(),
                    autoclose: true,
                    weekStart: 1
                     };
                
    /*            
                $scope.emailcheck = function () {
                    $scope.answer = EmailChecker.emailc($scope.staffForm.staffLogin.email);
                }
*/
                
                //////////////////per il number controller
                 $scope.wks =  {number: 1, name: 'testing'};
                /////////////////////////////////////////
                
                console.log($scope.staffForm.gender);
           
                //Now load the data from server  
                _refreshStaffData();  
           
                //HTTP POST/PUT methods for add/edit country   
                // with the help of id, we are going to find out whether it is put or post operation  
                  
                $scope.submitStaff = function() {  
                    console.log($scope.staffForm);   
                    if($scope.staffForm.name == "" || $scope.staffForm.surname == ""  || $scope.staffForm.staffLogin.email == "" || $scope.staffForm.birthDate == "" || $scope.staffForm.phone == "" || $scope.staffForm.gender == null || $scope.staffForm.idstaff == null)
                           _showSBNoField();   
                    else if(!_emailCheck($scope.staffForm.staffLogin.email))
                            _showSBInvalid();
                        
                  /*  else if(!angular._isDate($scope.staffForm.birthDate))
                           console.log("no date"); */
                    else{
                        if ($scope.staffForm.idstaff == -1) {  
                            console.log("StaffLogin");
                            console.log($scope.staffForm.staffLogin);
                            console.log($scope.staffForm);

                            //Id is absent in form data, it is create new country operation 
                            $scope.staffForm.birthDate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.staffForm.birthDate), "yyyy-MM-dd");  
                            console.log( $scope.staffForm.birthDate);
                            restService.insertstaff($scope.staffForm, _giveLast, _error);
                          /*  $http({  
                            method : 'POST',  
                            url : 'http://localhost:8080/FoodDrinkDispener/rest/staff',  
                            data : angular.toJson($scope.staffForm),  
                            headers : {  
                                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'  
                            }  
                        }).then( _giveLast, _error );  */
                          //  console.log("StaffLogin");


                        } else {  
                            //Id is present in form data, it is edit country operation  
                            //var dateformat = new String($scope.staffForm.birthDate);
                           // $scope.getdateold.getdateold =  $scope.staffForm.birthDate;
                            $scope.staffForm.birthDate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.staffForm.birthDate), "yyyy-MM-dd");  
                            console.log( $scope.staffForm.birthDate);
                          //  $scope.staffForm.phone = $scope.staffForm.phone.toString();
                         //   console.log( $scope.staffForm.phone);
                          //  console.log( new Date($scope.staffForm.birthDate));
                            
                            restService.updatestaff($scope.staffForm, _putStaffLogin, _error);
                            
                       /*     $http({  
                            method : 'PUT',  
                            url : 'http://localhost:8080/FoodDrinkDispener/rest/staff',  
                            data : angular.toJson($scope.staffForm),  
                            headers : {  
                                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'  
                            }
                        }).then( _putStaffLogin, _error ); */
                        } 

                        console.log("HTTP: ");
                        console.log($http);
                        console.log($scope.staffForm.gender);
                        console.log($scope.staffForm.idstaff);
                    }   
                };  
                //HTTP DELETE- delete country by Id  
           /*    $scope.deleteStaff = function(staff) {  
                    $http({  
                        method : 'DELETE',  
                        url : 'http://localhost:8080/FoodDrinkDispener/rest/staff/' + staff.idstaff  
                    }).then(_success, _error);  
                };  */
                
                 $scope.deleteStaff = function(staff) {  
                     $scope.staffForm.name = staff.name;  
                     $scope.staffForm.idstaff = staff.idstaff; 
                     $scope.staffForm.surname = staff.surname;   
                     $scope.staffForm.birthDate = staff.birthDate;  
                     $scope.staffForm.phone = staff.phone; 
                 //    $scope.staffForm.gender = staff.gender;  
                     $scope.selectg.type = staff.gender;  
                     //$scope.staffForm.staffLogin.idstaffLogin = staff.staffLogin.idstaff;
                     $scope.staffForm.staffLogin.email = staff.staffLogin.email;
                     $scope.staffForm.staffLogin.staff = "";
                     $scope.staffForm.working = false;  
            //       $scope.staffForm.pass = "prova";
                     console.log(staff.staffLogin.email);
                     restService.deletestaff($scope.staffForm, _success, _error);

                    }  
             
   
             // In case of edit, populate form fields and assign form.id with country id  
                $scope.editStaff = function(staff) {  
                    
                    console.log(staff.phone);
                    $scope.staffForm.name = staff.name;  
                    $scope.staffForm.idstaff = staff.idstaff; 
                    $scope.staffForm.surname = staff.surname;   
                 //   String a = staff.birthDate;
                    console.log(staff.birthDate);
                 //   $scope.staffForm.birthDate = $filter('date')(staff.birthDate, "mm/dd/yyyy");  
                    $scope.staffForm.birthDate = staff.birthDate;
                     console.log($scope.staffForm.birthDate);

                    $scope.staffForm.phone =  parseInt(staff.phone, 10);  // parseInt with radix; 
                    $scope.staffForm.gender = staff.gender;  
                    $scope.selectg.type = staff.gender;  
                    //$scope.staffForm.staffLogin.idstaffLogin = staff.staffLogin.idstaff;
                    $scope.staffForm.staffLogin.email = staff.staffLogin.email;
                    $scope.staffForm.staffLogin.staff = "";
            //        $scope.staffForm.pass = "prova";
                    console.log(staff.staffLogin.email);
                };  
           
          
                function _refreshStaffData() {  
             
                    restService.allstaffworking(_getstaff, _timeout, _error);
            
                }
                
                function _getstaff(response){
                    if (response.data == ""){
                        console.log("Accesso non autorizzato")
                    }
                    $scope.staffs = response.data;  
                }
           
                function _success(response) {  
                   // console.log(staff.name);
                    console.log("successo");
                    
                    _refreshStaffData();  
                    _clearFormData();
                    _showSB();
                    console.log("cleared");
                
                }  
                
                function _timeout() {  
                   // console.log(staff.name);
                    console.log("timeout token");

                    _showSBtimeout();
                
                }  
           
                function _error(response) {  
                    console.log("qualcosa è andata male");
                    console.log(response.statusText);  
                }  
           
                //Clear the form  
                function _clearFormData() {  
                    $scope.staffForm.idstaff = -1; 
                    $scope.staffForm.name = "";  
                    $scope.staffForm.surname = "";   
                    $scope.staffForm.birthDate = "";  
                    $scope.staffForm.phone = ""; 
                    $scope.staffForm.gender = true;
                    $scope.staffForm.staffLogin.idstaffLogin = -1;
                    $scope.staffForm.staffLogin.email = "";
                   // $scope.staffForm.staffLogin.pass = "";
                    $scope.staffForm.staffType.idstaffType=2;
                    $scope.staffForm.working= true;
              
                    
                };  
                
                function _giveLast(){ 
                    
                    console.log("yes");
                    console.log($scope.staffForm);
                     
                  //  $scope.staffLast = restService.laststaff;
                    restService.laststaff(_postStaffLogin);
               //     _postStaffLogin();
                   
                   
                                          
                }
           
            
                function _postStaffLogin(response){ 
                    $scope.staffLast = response.data;
                    console.log($scope.staffForm.staffLogin.email);
                    console.log($scope.staffLast.idstaff);
                     //console.log($scope.staffForm.staffLogin.idstafflogin);
                     //$scope.staffForm.staffLogin.staff = $scope.staffLast;
                    //$scope.staffLoginForm.staff = $scope.staffLast;
                    $scope.staffForm.staffLogin.email;
                 //   $scope.staffLoginForm.pass = $scope.staffForm.staffLogin.pass;
                    console.log($scope.staffLoginForm.idstaffLogin);
                    console.log($scope.staffLoginForm.email);
              //      console.log($scope.staffLoginForm.pass);
   
                    restService.insertstafflogin($scope.staffLoginForm, _success, _error);
                    
               
                }
                
                 function _putStaffLogin(){ 
                    
                     console.log("CIAOOOO");
                    $scope.staffLoginForm.idstaffLogin = $scope.staffForm.idstaff;
                    $scope.staffLoginForm.email = $scope.staffForm.staffLogin.email;
                 //   $scope.staffLoginForm.pass = "ab";
                    console.log($scope.staffLoginForm.idstaffLogin);
                    console.log($scope.staffLoginForm.email);
            //        console.log($scope.staffLoginForm.pass);
   
                     restService.updatestafflogin($scope.staffLoginForm, _success, _error);
                     
                   
                    x.className = "show";

                    // After 3 seconds, remove the show class from DIV
                    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
                }
                
                function _showSBNoField() {
                    // Get the snackbar DIV
                    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar_nofield")

                    // Add the "show" class to DIV
                    x.className = "show";

                    // After 3 seconds, remove the show class from DIV
                    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
                }
                
                 function _showSBInvalid() {
                    // Get the snackbar DIV
                    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar_invalid")

                    // Add the "show" class to DIV
                    x.className = "show";

                    // After 3 seconds, remove the show class from DIV
                    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
                }
                
                function _showSBtimeout() {
                    // Get the snackbar DIV
                    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar_timeout")

                    // Add the "show" class to DIV
                    x.className = "show";

                    // After 3 seconds, remove the show class from DIV
                    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
                }
                
                function _isDate(value) {
                    return toString.call(value) === '[object Date]';
                }
                
                
                function _emailCheck(emailStr) {
                    var emailPat = /^(.+)@(.+)$/;
                    var specialChars = "\\(\\)<>@,;:\\\\\\\"\\.\\[\\]";
                    var validChars = "[^\\s" + specialChars + "]";
                    var quotedUser = "(\"[^\"]*\")";
                    var ipDomainPat = /^\[(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\]$/;
                    var atom = validChars + "+";
                    var word = "(" + atom + "|" + quotedUser + ")";
                    var userPat = new RegExp("^" + word + "(\\." + word + ")*$");
                    var domainPat = new RegExp("^" + atom + "(\\." + atom + ")*$");
                    var matchArray = emailStr.match(emailPat);
                    if (matchArray == null) {
                        alert("L'email sembra essere sbagliata: (controlla @ e .)");
                        return false;
                    }
                    var user = matchArray[1];
                    var domain = matchArray[2];
                    if (user.match(userPat) == null) {
                        alert("La parte dell'email prima di '@' non sembra essere valida!");
                        return false;
                    }
                    var IPArray = domain.match(ipDomainPat);
                    if (IPArray != null) {
                        for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                            if (IPArray[i] > 255) {
                                alert("L'IP di destinazione non è valido!");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    var domainArray = domain.match(domainPat);
                    if (domainArray == null) {
                        alert("La parte dell'email dopo '@' non sembra essere valida!");
                        return false;
                    }
                    var atomPat = new RegExp(atom, "g");
                    var domArr = domain.match(atomPat);
                    var len = domArr.length;
                    if (domArr[domArr.length - 1].length < 2 ||
                        domArr[domArr.length - 1].length > 6) {
                        alert("Il dominio di primo livello (es: .com e .it) non sembra essere valido!");
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (len < 2) {
                        var errStr = "L'indirizzo manca del dominio!";
                        alert(errStr);
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
             }

                         
      }); 
      app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider.

                    when('/editEmployee', {
                       templateUrl: 'london.htm',
                    });

              
                 }]);
```

Where I have added appconfig for ng-route:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.

                when('/editEmployee', {
                   templateUrl: 'london.htm',
                });


             }]);
```

And this is the page that I want to show when I called the url: `file:///C:/Users/Giacomo%20B/Desktop/progetto%20mainetti/prove%20angular/fddWebapp/edit_employee.html#/editEmployee` , called "london.htm", a simple page to try it:

```html
<!-- saved from url=(0043)http://www.w3schools.com/angular/london.htm -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></head><body><h1>London</h1>
<h3>London is the capital city of England.</h3>
<p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
<p>{{msg}}</p></body></html>
```

In this way, it should works..but It doesn't work!!! 
[image]

There are these errors:

```html
angular.js:10765 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Giacomo%20B/Desktop/progetto%20mainetti/prove%20angular/fddWebapp/london.htm. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

angular.js:12520 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: london.htm (HTTP status: -1 )
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$compile/tpload?p0=london.htm&p1=-1&p2=
```

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local - It doesn't sound like this is an angular issue, but more an issue with trying to load a local file via javascript

Comment: no no, it's not a problem of scripts..

Comment: Hmm.. Well, its difficult to know exactly what your issue is when you are providing such a large amount of code. Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve? From what I can tell, your error really does looks like it's caused by you attempting to run this locally, instead of using a local web server (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649460/angularjs-access-local-json-files might be related)

Comment: Specifically, the error you're seeing is because Angular is attempting to use XMLHttpRequest to fetch the file, but that violates the same-origin policy, since almost all local files (even those in the same directory) are considered to have their own origin, so angular fails to load london.htm

Comment: Ok, I try the example on Server and it works. But Tryng my own application on server I have other errors

Comment: I had other problems with XMLHttpRequest, by I resolving insert CORS filters in my web.xml dependency... do you know how I can resolve without run as server?

Comment: You cannot use `ngRoute` on `File://` based websites, a server is **required** for routing, because it uses ajax.

Comment: I understand...and how I can do?

Comment: how can you do *what*?  you can't just double click the HTML file on your local disk and have it work with routing.  You **must** run a server, and use `http://localhost` or something similar.

Comment: I understand, thanks